# consistent spacing for list element content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to us a list element for a simple score board.
Example:

(- = white space)

player: 5-----Computer: 3-----

And I want the space of these li elements to stay the same when the numbers change.
Example(original):

|player: |5-----|Computer: |3-----|

Example(What I'm trying for):

|player: |11----|Computer: |3-----|

This is what I have right now:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

.scoreBox {
    border: 5px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="scores">
    <li class="scoreBox">Player: </li>
    <li class="scoreBox" id="playerScore"></li>
    <li class="scoreBox">Computer: </li>
    <li class="scoreBox" id="computerScore"></li>
</ul>
```

Thus far the output just squashes it all together.

I've been trying to find an alternate solution, like maybe using a series of div's. But I feel that probably isn't a "best practices" kinda thing.

Comment: I'm not sure it's appropriate to have them as a list. Or at least, not `Player:`; that's a label of a score, not a score itself, if this is a list of scores. I would think you'd want `<li class="scoreBox"><span class="scoreLabel">Player: </span><span id="playerScore"></span></li>` etc. Then I'd suggest using flexbox or CSS grid to layout the `li` and `span`s appropriately.

Comment: If you are trying to display data aligned as in a grid or table, there would not be anything wrong with displaying tabular data in a table or grid. (i.e. `table` elements)

Answer (score 1):

You can just set min-width and tweak some styles:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

li+li {
  min-width: 30px;
}

.scoreBox {
    border: 5px solid black;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I would have the `li` with the following to better align the items: `position: relative` & `vertical-align: top` otherwise this is a great solution :)